# Cannot get StatsD and Graphite to play

Tags: graphite, statsd

I've been fiddling trying to get StatsD to push information across to Graphite but am seeing the following in the graphite logs

```
[18/Jan/2013 08:12:12] code 400, message Bad request version ('1358518363')
[18/Jan/2013 08:12:12] "stats.statsd.bad_lines_seen 0 1358518363" 400 -
```

The information that is pushed from StatsD looks like (taken from logs)

```
19 Jan 00:12:12 - debug: Counters:
{ 'statsd.bad_lines_seen': 0,
  'statsd.packets_received': 0,
  'x.show.html': 0 }
Timers:
{ 'x.show.html.duration': [],
  'x.show.html.view_runtime': [],
  'x.show.html.db_runtime': [] }
Gauges:
{}
```

I have checked StatsD via TCP management interface and it believes that it's flushing to Graphite just fine even though every single flush seems to throw errors on Graphite's side:

```
~$ telnet localhost 8126                                                    
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
stats
uptime: 2021
messages.last_msg_seen: 2004
messages.bad_lines_seen: 0
graphite.last_flush: 1
graphite.last_exception: 2021
END
```

I'm not sure what I am looking for to solve this problem. At the moment I'm fiddling with config incase I missed something - my next step would be to jump into the StatsD code and find out why it thinks it's getting a 200 back instead of a 400. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check whether you have configured the graphite(carbon) listening hostname and port in your statsd configuration file? The value that you have to set is:

```
{
   graphiteHost: "127.0.0.1"
 , graphitePort: 2003
}
```

It is the default value for carbon